# JdbcTokenStore - bad performance

Tags: spring, oauth

I'm experiencing bad performance on Spring JdbcTokenStore, so I've investigated a bit and I found following slow queries:

```
delete from oauth_access_token where token_id = ?
select token_id, authentication from oauth_access_token where token_id = ? 
select token_id, token from oauth_access_token where authentication_id = ?
```

I've checked the tables and it seems that the scripts provided (for example, here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/test/resources/schema.sql) doesn't even define a primary key for oauth_access_token table.

How can I optimize the performance? Can i safely define token_id as PK for outh_access_token and add an unique index to authentication_id column?

Thanks
Giulio

Comment: The script you point to is for testing (hence the fact that it inside the `src/test` folder.

Comment: Yes, it seems that there's no 'official' DDL for that tables.
But still I would need to understand if I can put indexes on those columns...

Comment: I would say just try... Not sure about the unique on the `authentication_id` column... Depends on if a single result is expected or not, I would check the code for that.

Comment: What did you finally do? Did you add primary keys? Please let us know your experience, thanks a lot.

Comment: @johncol at the end, if I remember well I added the following indexes on "oauth_access_token" table:
- primary key on "token_id"
- unique index on "auth_id" column (because the query based on "auth_id" expected only one row)
- index on "refresh_token" column - don't remember if it was unique or not

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue with my spring boot app, after creating an unique index on the `token_id` column the performance improved drastically